# Extract flow file content from specific bytes to rename the flowfile

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to extract content from specific bytes from files to rename the flowfile.For e.g

```
appType - (4-6) bytes
sender - (8-22) bytes
receiver - (24-38) bytes
```

So flow file name should look like `apptype.sender.receiver.YYMMDDHHMMSSS`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ExtrctText with single-byte character set:

```
Character Set = "US-ASCII"
```

and then add following additional parameters to extract characters where first number - how many to skip and second - how many to take

```
appType  = .{3}(.{3})
sender   = .{7}(.{15})
receiver = .{23}(.{15})
```